# Record Search Query paths with Google Analytics Virtual Pageview

Tags: php, html, ajax, google-analytics

We are running WordPress with the Google Analytics by Yoast plugin. We also have an event calendar, which is based on AJAX. We need to track Virtual Pageviews so we can record the searches and the search queries.

How can we track the path of the search queries that are submitted? I am aware that the syntax for virtual pageviews is:

```
    ga(‘send’, ‘pageview’, ‘path of virtual page’);
```

Can that be modified to record the search query url (which would appear in the browser's address bar upon AJAX displaying the search results on the page) as opposed to a pre-determind page path?

This is the existing code for the button that users click to initiate a search:

```
<div class="tribe-bar-submit">
<input class="tribe-events-button tribe-no-param" type="submit" name="submit-bar"
value="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Find %s',
'the-events-calendar' ), tribe_get_event_label_plural() ); ?>" />
</div>
```

I believe modifying the code to the following will record a virtual pageview, but am not sure how to modify the last parameter to record the dynamic paths of the search queries:

```
<div class="tribe-bar-submit">
<input class="tribe-events-button tribe-no-param" type="submit" name="submit-bar"
onClick="ga(‘send’, ‘pageview’, ‘/path-of-static-page-here’)"
value="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Find %s',
'the-events-calendar' ), tribe_get_event_label_plural() ); ?>" />
</div>
```

Comment: This code will not work - for one you cannot drop the event tracking call into a piece of HTML like that, you'd need to add an event listener (onsubmit="ga('send'...).

Comment: @EikePierstorff thank you for calling out that error. I had forgotten to include the event listener. Will it need to be onSubmit or would onClick work as well?